# How to write query to select all rows between now and last 1 day in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this question might be a duplicate one but I couldn't find any suitable answer. My query I'm tryign is the following

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE MY_DATE_COLUMN between datetime('now', 'start of days')
    AND datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

and then I added a record 10 mins ago and retrieved it. But 0 rows returned. 
If my query is wrong, could you please help me fix it?

Comment: There is no `-start of days` [modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Choose correct ones.

Comment: wait .., lemme try again.

Comment: It is `start of day` not `days`

Comment: great @cricket_007, it works like magic. I thought I will get syntax error if I wrote unsuitable modifier. thank you.

Comment: Nope, just no results because the date function probably defaults to some value. The link posted above has correct modifiers

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query in this way:

```
select * from MY_TABLE where MY_DATE_COLUMN > datetime('now','-1 day') order by MY_DATE_COLUMN;
```

MY_DATE_COLUMN > datetime('now','-1 day') takes all rows in the last day.

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INCIDENTS + " WHERE "
    + DATE_OF_EVENT + ">=" + "datetime('now','- 1day')"; is my previous query before that one. That didn't work.

Comment: @CristyYG that didn't work because you're missing a space between 1 and day